# Error: String Indices must be integers

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a json string to a csv file. 
I am getting the `error:String Indices must be integers`
(All the nested keys are in the correct format).
Does the square bracket here is the reason for that?

```
data":[\
```

Following is the python file that i am trying to execute:

```
import csv
import json

x="""{

"response":{"status":1,"httpStatus":200,"data":{"page":1,"current":50,"count":11012,"pageCount":221,

"data":[\
{"Offer":{"name":"abc","id":"884"},
"Affiliate":{"company":"POCKET","id":"1494"},
"Goal":{"name":null},
"Stat":{"year":"2015","month":"03","hour":"11","date":"2015-03-13","impressions":"0","gross_clicks":"1","unique_clicks":"1","clicks":"1","conversions":"0"}},

{"Offer":{"name":"qwerty","id":"884"},"Affiliate":{"company":"Rob","id":"1472"},"Goal":{"name":null},"Stat":{"year":"2015","month":"03","hour":"17","date":"2015-03-07","impressions":"0","gross_clicks":"2","unique_clicks":"2","clicks":"2","conversions":"0"}},


{"Offer":{"name":"1000","id":"2586"},"Affiliate":{"company":"Iron","id":"1156"},"Goal":{"name":null},"Stat":{"year":"2015","month":"07","hour":"13","date":"2015-07-07","impressions":"0","gross_clicks":"8628","unique_clicks":"8620","clicks":"8628","conversions":"6"}}],"dbSource":"brdb"},"errors":[],"errorMessage":null}}"""



x = json.loads(x)

f = csv.writer(open("S2.csv", "w",newline=""))
# Write CSV Header, If you dont need that, remove this line
f.writerow(["Offer", "Affiliate", "Goal", "year", "month","hour", "date", "impressions", "gross_clicks", "unique_clicks","clicks","conversions"])
print(x)
for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["response"]["data"]["data"]["Offer"]["name"], 
                x["response"]["data"]["data"]["Affiliate"]["company"], 
                x["response"]["data"]["data"]["Goal"]["name"], 
                x["response"]["data"]["data"]["Stat"]["year"],
                x["response"]["data"]["data"]["Stat"]["month"],
                x["response"]["data"]["data"]["Stat"]["hour"],
                x["response"]["data"]["data"]["Stat"]["date"],
                x["response"]["data"]["data"]["Stat"]["impressions"],
                x["response"]["data"]["data"]["Stat"]["gross_clicks"],
                x["response"]["data"]["data"]["Stat"]["unique_clicks"],
                x["response"]["data"]["data"]["Stat"]["clicks"],
                x["response"]["data"]["data"]["Stat"]["conversions"]
                ])


f.writerow([""])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x["response"]["data"]["data"]` returns a list.

So `x["response"]["data"]["data"]["Offer"]` raises an error, as you are trying to access the key `Offer` in a list. Hence the error `List Indices must be integers`

Try this:

```
x["response"]["data"]["data"][0]["Offer"]["name"]
```

Where `x["response"]["data"]["data"][0]` will access the dictionary in the within the list, from which you can access the keys `"Offer"` and `"name"`